# Android App DeviceAnywhere LogCat

Tags: android, device, logcat

Is there a way to look at LogCat when the app is running on a device on DeviceAnywhere?

Thanks
Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try the perfecto mobile service. they have a button just for that called "get log"

www.perfectomobile.com
free registration and better prices than deviceanywhere

Answer (score 1):

http://developer.motorola.com/docstools/library/Testing_Your_Application_With_the_Virtual_Developer_Lab/ would indicate adb will work normally if you have acquired the device.